# Elm Lists of types & type aliases -- getting the extracted Lists to recognize the type

Tags: compiler-errors, elm

Working on my model. I've made a type to hold a list of my items:

```
type alias Item =
    { id : ItemId
    , containerId : ItemId
    , title : String
    , children : Items
    }


type Items
    = Items (List Item)

findByTitle : String -> Items -> Items
findByTitle title (Items items) =
    List.filter (\item -> item.title == title) items
```

```
The definition of `findByTitle` does not match its type annotation.
The type annotation for `findByTitle` says it always returns:
    Items
But the returned value (shown above) is a:
    List { children : Items, containerId : ItemId, id : ItemId, title : String }
```

The 2nd argument to function `getItemById` is causing a mismatch.
Function `getItemById` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:
    Items
But it is:
    List Item

```
getAllContainers : Item -> Items -> Items
getAllContainers item (Items items) =
    let
        container =
            (getItemById item.containerId items)  -- error below
    in
        case container of
            Nothing ->
                --  We assume that if a container is not in the list, it must be the root
                []

            Just containerItem ->
                containerItem :: getAllContainers containerItem items


getItemById : ItemId -> Items -> Maybe Item
getItemById id (Items items) =
    List.filter (\item -> id == item.id) items
        |> List.head
```

```
The 2nd argument to function `getItemById` is causing a mismatch.
Function `getItemById` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:
    Items
But it is:
    List Item
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the true list by pattern matching to expose the inner list. Here is an example of this concept occurring in a top level function:

```elm
myFunc : Items -> Html msg
myFunc (Items innerItems) =
    List.map func innerItems
```

**edit**

For your supplied function, if you are returning `Items`, you will need to "wrap" the list of items back up in the `Items` constructor:

```elm
findByTitle : String -> Items -> Items
findByTitle title (Items items) =
    Items (List.filter (\item -> item.title == title) items)
```

Comment: Can you add the function code to your example? That will help us target your exact problem

Comment: So the type annotation does not type the parameters?

And one puts the type _before_ the parameter name?

Comment: I added one, I still playing slap-and-tickle with the parameters on the others, but it's definitely better.

I have never seen types in a parameter list before. Any documentation for it?

Comment: I've added an example specific to your update. You may want to look more into pattern matching, which can happen both in a function definition as well as case statements. Here is a (slightly outdated) cheat sheet which offers more insight: https://gist.github.com/yang-wei/4f563fbf81ff843e8b1e

Comment: Thank you. I promise to write this up so you will have this question less frequently